# Getting Json Response from an API using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am newbie with javascript and jquery and i am facing a problem in json parsing with jquery.
I am using open weather simplest API for fetching the weather information but nothing is happening. If i hardcode the json in any file or in my script it works fine but as soon as i use URL of API it stop showing result.

here is my complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var path = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Lahore,pk";
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                $.getJSON(path, function (data) {
                    $.each(result, function (i, field) {
                        $("div").append(field + " ");
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Get JSON data</button>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are looping through `result`. Where is it's definition ?

Comment: Where did you get the variable **result**? Did you mean it as **data**?

Comment: Missing `http://` at the start of `path`. But does that website support CORS or JSONP? You should check your console for errors. Very important when debugging Javascript

Comment: Move the ready handler from the inside of myFunction.

Comment: @A1rPun . no i told that for Json format output  print method.. example: alert(JSON.stringify(data)); data is his response

Comment: @Bilal Amjad check your path (http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Lahore,pk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did multiple mistakes. Here a working fiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="myButton">Get JSON data</button>

<div id="mydiv"></div>

</body>
<script>
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    var path = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Lahore,pk";
    $.getJSON(path, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, field) {
            var textNode = document.createTextNode(i+ " " +JSON.stringify(field));
            $("#mydiv").append(textNode);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yksf092x/2/)

Write a comment if you need more information.

Comment: Yes its working! Thanks a lot for the help and yes i know i have done multiple mistakes as i am newbie.

Comment: Seeing you are new. If my answer was helpful for you, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: It is fetching the complete response perfectly but how can i  get specific data like from the result if i want to know the temperature only how can i get that? Right now i am using this approach using your code:

 '$.getJSON(path, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, field) {
            var textNode = document.createTextNode(i+ " " +JSON.stringify(field));
            $("#mydiv").append(textNode);
            obj = JSON.parse(textNode);
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = obj.main.temp;'

Comment: If you want to access fields in your response object do it like this:
`$.getJSON(path, function (data) {
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = data.main.temp;
});`

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a lot! Now let me see how can i vote and mark your answer as answered :)

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the JSON result, ie. `data` in your case, :

Working Code:

```
<button>Get JSON data</button>
<div></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var path = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Lahore,pk";
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                $.getJSON(path, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, field) {
                        $("div").append(JSON.stringify(field)); // parse the object according to your need.
                    });
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: The `openweathermap` doesn't seem to support HTTPS, so your relative protocol would break here.